# let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_{n+1}-a_n=1+(-1)^n$ , is the sequence bounded? does it converge?

Tags: real-analysis

> let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_{n+1}-a_n=1+(-1)^n$
>
> 1. $a_n$ is bounded
> 2. $a_n$ converges (including infinity)

---

The first statement is not true (it is not bounded ) because it is an increasing sequence so it is only bounded from below. $$a_{n+1}=a_n+1+(-1)^n$$ $$\implies$$ $$a_{n+1} \geq a_n$$

this is according to a statement I read in the book that says an increasing sequence is only bounded from below and not above.

for the second statement:

we have $a_n = a_{n+1} -1 -(-1)^n$ $\implies$
$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
 a_{n+1}-2&\text{if}\, n _{even}\\
 a_{n+1}&\text{if}\, n_{odd}\\
\end{cases}
$

I thought that it does not converge because it seems similar to $a_n = (-1)^n$ but according to the book the right answer is that yes it is convergent , why is that?

Thanks for any tips and help!

EDIT - Taking another look at it , does it converge to infinity? because $-2$ does not affect $a_{n+1}$ is it is increasing to infinity then the limit will be infinity

Comment: *Hint:* $a_{n+2} = a_n + 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Regarding your solution for the first task, notice that a sequence can be increasing *and* bounded. For example, $a_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$ is increasing and bounded by $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when we say "converge" we mean that it "converges" to a finite value. In other words, if $a_n \to \infty$ we say that the sequence diverges.

Regardless, for sequences that are reasonably easy to compute it's always good to compute the first few terms. Let's say the first term $a_1$ is $a$. Then:
$$
a_1 = a, \; a_2 = a, \; a_3 = a + 2, \; a_4 = a + 2, \; a_5 = a + 4, \; a_6 = a + 4, \; a_7 = a + 6,\dots
$$
So heuristically you should see that $a_n$ increases to infinity. This is not hard to prove - you have noticed that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$, and as Martin R mentioned in the comments, $a_{n+2} = a_n + 2$. Can you proceed from here?